# T SQL How to use: Sum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, procedure

TABLE a

```
ID        |  BALANCE
100.01    |  0
100.01.01 |  156.00
100.01.02 |  155.12
100.02    |  0
100.02.01 |  45.40
100.02.02 |  44.40
```

procedure

```
CREATE Procedure sp_Test (@startId varchar(120))
    AS
    SELECT a.Id,
           SUM(a.Balance),
       INTO #tempA
    FROM a
    GROUP BY a.Id
    GO
    SELECT b.Id
           ,SUM(b.Balance)
       INTO #tempB
    FROM a
    GROUP BY a.Id
    GO
    SELECT x.ID
           ,x.Name
           ,SUM(@tempA.Balance)
           ,SUM(@tempB.Balance)
    FROM a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @tempA ON a.Id = @tempA.Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @tempB ON a.Id = @tempB.Id
    WHERE a.Id LIKE @startId + '.%'
```

My English is not enough to tell the problem. (translate) :( 
i want to do RESULT

exec sp_Test '100.01'

```
ID          Balance
100.01   |  311.12
```

exec sp_Test '100.02'

```
ID          Balance
100.02   |  89,8
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

use SUM() with GROUP BY

```
declare @startId as varchar(120);

SELECT  LEFT(a.ID, LEN(@startId)) as ID,
        SUM(a.BALANCE) as BALANCE
FROM    TableA a
WHERE   a.ID LIKE @startId + '%'
GROUP BY LEFT(a.ID, LEN(@startId))
```